# Оператор-друг не видит приватные поля класса

Tags: c++, классы, операторы

Оператор-друг не видит приватные поля класса. Выдает две ошибки:

1. Ошибка (активно) E0265   член "List::size" (объявлено в строке 22 из "D:\CODES\dsa\d\listHead.h") недоступно d   D:\CODES\dsa\d\listRes.cpp  82
2. Ошибка (активно) E0265   член "List::ptr" (объявлено в строке 23 из "D:\CODES\dsa\d\listHead.h") недоступно  d   D:\CODES\dsa\d\listRes.cpp  83

Ошибки в listRes.cpp. Ниже предаставлен код класса. Ошибка в операторе >>

```
class List {
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, List& a);
private:
    int size;
    int* ptr;
};
```

```
// listRes.cpp
#include "listHead.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

istream& operator>> (istream& in, List& a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size; i++)
        in >> a.ptr[i];
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Вам следует убрать из вопроса код, не относящийся к проблеме.

Comment: В `istream& operator>> (istream& in, List& a) {` ошибка есть, но другая - он не возвращает значение, хотя должен...

Comment: ... и проверить, что приведенный код действительно порождает указанную ошибку. Подсказка: [mcve] для этого кода состоит из одной строки, а все остальное - мусор, не относящийся к проблеме.

Comment: @Harry дописал ``` return in; ```. Не помогает.

Comment: Если код исполняю в одном файле, то все работает корректно. Что может быть причиной?

Comment: Ну, этот код вообще не должен компилироваться - у вас первым включается `listhead.h`, который не включает ничего другого, так что компилятор не знает, что такое `istream`, например...

Comment: @Harry попробывал включить сначало <iostream> - не помогло.

Comment: А чем компилируете?

Comment: @Harry Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил таким образом. Добавил в файл заголовка пространство имен std (using namespace std;). Всем спасибо кто откликся.